# How to run a PHP script continuously on a virtual host server?

Tags: php, database, cron

I have a scheduling application which has to execute a specific task based on the schedule set by the user. This means the PHP script has to continuously check the Database and compare with the current time and see if there is any match. Obviously, I cannot run an infinite loop.

Other options include cron job. However, since I'm running all this on a virtual host server I'm not sure if I can schedule a PHP script to run every few seconds based on a cronjob. Am I thinking right and is there another alternative? Or can I execute cronjobs on virtual hosts (where i don't have much flexibility)?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "chron job"- to extend my answer, it depends on your host and running platform, but if you need something to run "every couple of seconds" you may want to reconsider how you currently have your system setup as that can be load heavy, especially with a large amount of users.

Comment: @Jhecht You mean cron right and not chron? What are your suggestions for changing the system setup? yes, I will have a lot of users.

Comment: "Obviously, I cannot run an infinite loop" - Why not?

Comment: "can I execute cronjobs on virtual hosts". Have you asked your provider?

Comment: Also, consider a trigger in MySQL.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm avoiding infinite loop as it might increase the load on my server drastically if I'm trying to poll every 5 secs. Also, since I'm on a virtual host, the provider might not allow this.

Comment: @vascowhite Thanks I'll check that.

Comment: @AGM: by "virtual host", do you mean a shared host? A virtual host sounds like a VPS provider, and with that, you get a root access.

Comment: @halfer Yes, it is a shared host. I don't have root access.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a php script in an endless loop, however I'm not sure if this really make sense.

You can manipulate the php settings in your php script to remove the maximum execution time. About the the cronjob I would directly call the php5 executable to run your script, with some logic to avoid double executions. E.g. write the current time to a lock file so if the last time is older than let's say 5 minutes you script crashed and should start now. If not just exit.

Answer (score 0):

Cron will let you schedule by the minute, not second. So, your script will have to take care of a full minute (or more) and  exit after a timeout so as to let the next loop (cron-initiated task) take after it. However, you might run into overlapping problems, so your script must check first of all, whether another instance of itself is already running.

You may want to check this : http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/ for how to make a PHP script become a daemon (and thus, execute in the background without relying on Cron).

Do you have the possibility to hook treatments to the "insert" action of your users? (ie. whenever someone adds a job to the queue). If yes, you could use a background process (daemon, see link above) which would listen to a Unix socket, and your Add Job action would publish into this socket. This avoids having to poll actively and repeatedly from the database to check whether new jobs were registered.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think my capabilities might be limited because I'm on a virtual host and I do not have the rights to install Pear or other packages. But I will surely request for it. I didn't quite understand your last paragraph. Can you explain further?

Comment: In my last paragraph, I mean: do you have control over the way the user will add items to the schedule?